# Strange behavior of solution to $- \frac{\partial^2 \psi\left(x\right)}{\partial x^2} - e^{-\alpha x} \psi =0$

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, special-functions

Say we have the following equation the following equation (inspired from quantum mechanics with 
$V\left(x\right) = - e^{- \alpha x}$):

\begin{align} \label{eq:first-eq}
- \frac{\partial^2 \psi\left(x\right)}{\partial x^2} - e^{-\alpha x} \psi =0 \tag{1}
\end{align}

According to Mathematica the solutions are linear combinations of Bessel functions:

\begin{align} \label{eq:second-eq}
\psi\left(x\right) = A J_{0} \left(\frac{2}{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x/2} \right) + B Y_{0} \left(\frac{2}{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x/2} \right)  \tag{2}
\end{align}

The code:

```
eq = -D[ψ[x], {x, 2}] - E^(-α*x)*ψ[x] == 0
DSolve[eq, ψ[x], x]
{{ψ[x] -> 
BesselJ[0, (2 Sqrt[E^(-x α)])/α] C[1] + 2 BesselY[0, (2 Sqrt[E^(-x α)])/α] C[2]}}
```

However, some is strange about this solution. Specifically notice that if we consider the equation:

$$- \frac{\partial^2 \psi\left(x\right)}{\partial x^2} - e^{\alpha x} \psi =0 $$

Which is Eq. \ref{eq:first-eq} but with $\alpha \rightarrow -\alpha $, then we should get Eq. \ref{eq:second-eq} with the $\alpha \rightarrow -\alpha $. However, instead we get:

$$ 
\psi\left(x\right) = A J_{0} \left(\frac{2}{\alpha }e^{\alpha x/2} \right) + B Y_{0} \left(\frac{2}{\alpha }e^{\alpha x/2} \right) 
$$

```
eq = -D[ψ[x], {x, 2}] - E^(α*x)*ψ[x] == 0
DSolve[eq, ψ[x], x]
{{ψ[x] -> 
{{ψ[x] -> BesselJ[0, (2 Sqrt[E^(x α)])/α] C[1] + 2 BesselY[0, (2 Sqrt[E^(x α)])/α] C[2]}}
```

I know that $J_{0}$ is even but $Y_{0}$ is not, what is happening?
Also, **which of the solutions is actually correct?**

Comment: But then, you should be adding initial conditions that express the fact that $\psi(x)$ is regular at the origin, no?

Comment: Sorry I might be misunderstanding @J.M., if I plot this function it looks regular at the origin $x = 0 $ ... Or how would you do that?

Answer (score 7):

They are both correct:

```
eq = -D[ψ[x], {x, 2}] - E^(-α*x)*ψ[x] == 0;
DSolve[eq, ψ, x];
FullSimplify[eq /. First[%]]

(*Out[70]= True*)

eq = -D[ψ[x], {x, 2}] - E^(α*x)*ψ[x] == 0;
DSolve[eq, ψ, x];
FullSimplify[eq /. First[%]]

(*Out[67]= True*)
```

The parity of `BesselJ` and `BesselY` is completely irrelevant, given that their arguments are neither even or odd in `α`.  And since you have two free constants any way, what's the contradiction?